# Group by gap time - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by, timestamp

I need to do in PostgreSQL a count of records that are repeated in a time interval less than 40 minutes, as in this example:

```
Table

2019-01-27 09:55:18
2019-01-27 10:03:20
2019-01-27 10:12:14
2019-01-27 11:05:37
2019-01-27 11:27:52
2019-01-27 13:35:28
2019-01-27 15:36:41

Result

Count
3
2
1
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select 
   round(extract(epoch from timestamp ts_column)/(60*40)),
   count(1)
  from Table
 group by round(extract(epoch from timestamp ts_column)/(60*40))
```